# Django problem with POST method

Tags: python, django, forms, post, get

I am having an issue with using POSTed data instead of GET data with Django.

Here's my simplified urlpatterns class:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^hello/$', hello),
    ('^hello/ajax_info/$', ajax_info),   
)
```

And I have this view in the views.py file:

```
def ajax_info(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print "This is a post"
    # do stuff
```

The web page served up when you browse /hello/ has this javascript in it:

```
    function loadXMLDoc(name) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                //window.onload()

            }
        }

        // GET method
        //parm = values
        //xmlhttp.open("GET",name+"?q="+parm, true);
        //xmlhttp.send();

        // POST method
        parms = "data=" + values
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "ajax_info", false);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        xmlhttp.send(parms)
    } // end function loadXMLDoc
```

(in the web page I have a button that causes loadXMLDoc() to get called when you press it)

If I uncomment the "GET method" in the javascript, and comment out the "POST method" then my, django view gets called.

But if I comment out the "GET method" and use the "POST method" code, then my viewer doesn't even get called.  And the django dev server returns this:

```
[28/May/2011 00:15:06] "POST /hello/ajax_info HTTP/1.1" 500 69236
```

Am I missing something obvious?  The examples seem to indicate that my request should get to my viewer even if they are POSTs.

Comment: and the bool parameter to the open call in the javascript (false in the example) doesn't seem to matter.  true also doesn't work, with the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your view method does not return anything ... Try accesing the page /hello/ajax_info/ and check if everything is working properly!

If this is the case, you will receive, with DEBUG = True, this error:
"The view ... didn't return an HttpResponse object."

Also be sure you are using the "csrf_token" tag if you are POSTing something ... Cookies must be on!

Comment: My view method isn't even getting called by Django when I issue a POST.  If I access the page directly as you suggest, it works (because that is a GET I guess)

Comment: Ok, then try POST something on the page without ajax ... A simple form will do!.. If it works with GET, then the bug is generated with the POST method ... But if it doesn't print you the "This is a post" message, then something died along the way! My hunch is CSRF protection ... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with django, but that `500` sure looks like an HTTP status code, indicating that your response was bad.  Perhaps watch what happens with a JavaScript debugger: Firebug, Chrome's tools, Opera Dragonfly, etc.

Incidentally, you may want to use a library like jQuery for the client code.  Manual ajax is a massive headache.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you do not understand how to debug ajax in browser.

Read this http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/Debugging+AJAX+requests+using+Firebug and then use this technique to find what exactly crashes your ajax view.

Comment: Wow, thanks.  Your debug howto revealed this:  
Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Answer (score 1):

I remember at some point I had an issue where POST and ajax would not work properly when I forced the url to end with "/". I guess it's worth a shot to try and remove it.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^hello/$', hello),
    ('^hello/ajax_info$', ajax_info), # Removed ending slash   
)
```

Comment: That doesn't fix it, but it does change the HTTP response error code from 500 to 403.